# Is it possible to search static cells in UITableview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a `UITableView` with static cells made through Interface Builder.

Is it possible to search through these cells using a search bar? I have been trying to implement it but can't seem to get anywhere. For a search bar would the tableview have to use dynamic cells or can the search be done with static cells or can I search by the labels of the cells?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement a search of static cells in a table. However, since the data source behind your table is hidden in the `UITableViewContoller`, you need to put in the "clues" for your search into the cells themselves.

I would strongly caution against using the standard cell classes, because they provide no place to store the data on which you search, except for a label or two. Using labels, however, is not a good choice, because it may hamper your localization efforts.

A better approach would be to define a custom class for your `UITableViewCell`, introduce additional properties on which to search, set these properties in the Interface Builder through the User Defined Runtime Attributes section of the Identity Inspector, and use these attributes during the searches initiated by the `UISearchBar`.

Here is an example: define a class for your custom cell

```
@interface SearchableTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSString *searchString;
@end
```

In the Identity Inspector of each static cell, choose `SearchableTableViewCell` for the type. In the User Defined Runtime Attributes panel, click [+], choose "string" for the type, enter `searchString` for the name, and set the searchable content into the value.

Now your `UISearchBarDelegate` can take cells from `UITableView`'s `dataSource`, cast them to `SearchableTableViewCell`, and examine their `searchString` property to determine if the cell should be included into search results or not.

When your search is over, you may need to highlight cells that have been found, or to hide cells that do not fit the search criteria. While highlighting can be done without altering the data source, hiding requires more significant overrides. [Here is a question discussing approaches to hiding static cells in a `UITableView`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8260267/335858).