# Are UITableViews laid out in Interface Builder using the "Static Cells" option modifiable via code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableView set to static cells. Is it possible to hide some of the cells programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260267/uitableview-set-to-static-cells-is-it-possible-to-hide-some-of-the-cells-progra)

Using storyboards, a `UITableView` can be laid out entirely in Interface Builder by changing the content mode to "Static Cells" instead of "Dynamic Prototypes." This is extremely useful in creating certain types of UIs, but it seems to have its limitations.

I want to lay out a layout using static cells, but I want a portion of the table view to show/hide itself based on a switch in another table view cell. Is this possible using static cells, or will I have to go with the traditional method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following solution to hide the cells: [UITableView set to static cells. Is it possible to hide some of the cells programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260267/uitableview-set-to-static-cells-is-it-possible-to-hide-some-of-the-cells-progra)

and then show/hide them with an on/off BOOL.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a duplicate flag.

Comment: My bad, I still haven't gotten the hang of flagging yet.