# Xcode remove cell with animation programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios8

Hi i have been searching around to find a way to remove a static cell with animation but i have not found a solution to the problem.
I have also tried: `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`
 but no success.

Comment: What do you mean by no success?  The animation is not shown?  The cells do not delete?

Comment: Not deleted or animation.

Comment: Are you removing the cell from the datasource?

Comment: I have no datasource it is just on a storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide cell before it is shown, in UITableViewDelegate's `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. This is the last method in your control where you can manipulate the cell display. It does not remove the space the cell takes, so another thing you can try is to set cell row's height to 0 using the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method of the same protocol.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      if (yourCell) {
          return 0;
      } else {
      return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As your tableview is static, you cannot use `deleteRowsAtIndexPath`.  The best option would probably be to migrate your data into a dataSource method for the tableview.

If this is impossible, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260267/uitableview-set-to-static-cells-is-it-possible-to-hide-some-of-the-cells-progra) (*"UITableView set to static cells. Is it possible to hide some of the cells programmatically?"*) gives that the best method is to use the third party library

**StaticDataTableViewController 2.0** (https://github.com/xelvenone/StaticDataTableViewController).

Otherwise you have to use the somewhat hacky method of changing the row height to 0.