# Swift: Shall I use static or dynamic tableviews for a table that has predefined static content but its layout changes due to dropdown expandable cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, static

I would like to implement a tableview that has static content. The only thing is that I want the table to include 'dropdown' cells. So when a user taps on one of the cells, the cell below it resizes from 0 height to its new height creating a drop down effect (expandable cell). 
I am not sure if I should use static or dynamic tableviews as I am changing the layout of some of the cells in runtime however all the content (as well as table sections and rows) is static and predefined in design. What is the correct implementation?

Comment: I’d try static cells with this trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/19276097/7132300

Comment: You want to stretch a cell from `0` height to a new height underneath the cell that was selected? This is definitely the behavior you want?

Comment: @iabuseservers Yes thats what I want to get a drop down effect